# PHP format decimal part of number

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have number `0.000432532` i want to break decimal part thousands like this

```
0.000 432 532
```

`number_format()` is only formats the whole part of the float, not decimal part.

Is there single function that can do it?

Comment: @Fibbe formatting both sides using the number_format will remove the leading 0 from the decimal part

Comment: How you even format both sides with numbr_format()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if there is a better solution but regex will do it.

```
$re = '/(\d{3})/'; // match three digits
$str = '0.000432532';
$subst = '$1 '; // substitute with the digits + a space

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

https://regex101.com/r/xNcfq9/1

This has a limitation, the number can not be larger 99 or the integer part of the number will start to "break" up.
But it seems as you only use small numbers.

Comment: but 100.005 will result in 100 . 005

Comment: @Mehdi correct. I just added that. I wrote it while you commented

Comment: tbh probably the best solution. All php functions to handle thousands breaks etc I know of, is before the decimal

Comment: Limitation is bit strict but for my goal its okay as max number i use it on is 2.x

Comment: @Roman I thought so too. Normally when you have lots of decimals you don't have very high numbers

Answer (score 1):

Andreas answer will work fine as long as you use numbers that are smaller than 99, however if you are planning to use >99 numbers, I suggest this:

```
$input = '0.000432532';

// Explode number
$input = explode('.', $input);

// Match three digits
$regex = '/(\d{3})/';
$subst = '$1 '; // substitute with the digits + a space
// Use number format for the first part
$input[0] = number_format($input[0], 0, '', ' ');
// User regex for the second part
$input[1] = preg_replace($regex, $subst, $input[1]);

echo implode($input, '.');
```

this one will work for all numbers

Answer (score 1):

A regex method will be more efficient than all this various array conversion, but just for the sake of argument, it can be done without regex:

```
list($int, $dec) = explode('.', $number);
$result = implode('.', [$int, implode(' ', str_split($dec, 3))]);
```

for a regex, I think this should handle most cases:

```
$formatted = preg_replace('/(\d+\.\d{3}|\d{3})(?!$)/', '$1 ', $number);
```